# send mail with doc file attachment

Tags: attachment, php

i am sending an e-mail with a doc file attachment. I am receiving the mail but with no any attachment.

**PHP**

```
$file_resume = '';
if (!empty($_FILES['attachment_file_name']['tmp_name'])) {
$file = $_FILES['attachment_file_name']['name'];
$attachment= file_get_contents($file);
$attachment= chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment));

}

$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$headers= "From: no-reply@edu.in"."\r\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To: no-reply@edu.in"."\r\n";
$headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$uid."\"\r\n";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"."\r\n Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$attachment."\"\r\n";

$message = $_POST['person_name'];

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

**Html**

```
    <form id="attachment" action='mailer.php' method='POST' name="attachment" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    person name: <input type="text" name="person_name" >
<br />
   Attachment : <input id="attachment_file" class="field" style="height: 25px;" type="file" name="attachment_file_name" />

    <input id="submit_button"  type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Use a class or library like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: @luk3thomas - That's the boundary for the message blocks. What I don't see is the email body with the boundaries demarking the body of the email and each block of encoded attachment content. Where is `$message` defined?

Comment: sir i have change my code.. can you please give me update with my code.

Comment: I again suggest using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) or [SwitfMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of trying to setup the mail packet formatting yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to try to manually send an email with attachment(s), you need to get to know the underlying mail text packet that actually represents what you're constructing with the `mail()` arguments. Unless you *comprehend* and *understand* what's going on here, you'll struggle to ever get your email with attachment to send. There's too many sharp edges.

Gmail has a nifty feature on emails to view the *original message packet*, in plaintext. It's called **Show Original**. When testing your email script, use a Gmail account if you can so you can inspect the actual email plaintext packet. To Show Original, go to the top, left dropdown triggered by the down arrow next to the reply arrow of an email.

So sending a test email to myself with an image attached, we have what's below. Your mail call, essentially, has to translate into something more or less like this example.

Especially note how the headers start off (the top five headers below you will not handle, except maybe `MIME-Version`). At the end of that block, you have:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=089e0118416874703004d86a5106
```

The part following the `=` is a *message part boundary*, which allows you to add multipart message blocks, including *attachment* file contents that have been encoded and given appropriate sub-part headers.

So there's:

```
--089e0118416874703004d86a5106

... message block(s) ...

--089e0118416874703004d86a5106--
```

There's actually another boundary declared, with:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=089e0118416874702b04d86a5104
```

Which involves the `text/plain` and `text/html` dual message formats. This is not required, but many mail clients do it by nature. You can choose either `text/plain` or `text/html`, it's up to you and how your comment is formatted.

Next we see:

```
--089e0118416874703004d86a5106
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="opinion (2).jpg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="opinion (2).jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hejlmnuz0

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIEBAYIBggICAgICAgICAgKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoK
... lots of lines for the encoded file block ...
W5R3W8ajLwrgUJEDGKWN2kWvO5iB7qdKwB6MwwfqVrQKcObveZxZBtQNCp0vc//Z
--089e0118416874703004d86a5106--
```

Note that the boundary's have a trailing `--` at the *end* of their blocks (not each block).

Take a look below and compare that to the code that luk3thomas has in his answer. Try sending a very simple email message to yourself, and compare that to an attachment-formatted email:

```
mail('your@email.com', 'Simple mail test', 'Test message body content.');`
```

You should start to get the idea what's required to send emails with attachments included. The thing is, formatting an email packet for sending is very particular and little things can cause it to fail. So you have to pay attention.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.50.40.164 with HTTP; Thu, 21 Mar 2013 00:30:51 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 02:30:51 -0500
Delivered-To: [redacted]@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CAKJE7RAH3+ZgN+86xykJrrzVaHK3waPD-a-OXbSDe3FGgcQrMw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test of email with attachment for plaintext
From: Jared Farrish <[redacted]@gmail.com>
To: Jared Farrish <[redacted]@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=089e0118416874703004d86a5106

--089e0118416874703004d86a5106
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=089e0118416874702b04d86a5104

--089e0118416874702b04d86a5104
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

This is the body of the email message.

--089e0118416874702b04d86a5104
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">This is the body of the email message.<br></div>

--089e0118416874702b04d86a5104--
--089e0118416874703004d86a5106
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="opinion (2).jpg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="opinion (2).jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hejlmnuz0

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIEBAYIBggICAgICAgICAgKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoK
CgoKCgwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/2wBDAQIICBAQEBAQEBAgICAgIEBAQEBA
QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQED/wgARCAEsASwDASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAgIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAABgcFCAIDBAkAAf/EABsBAAMBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAA
[-- snip many lines of base64 file contents --]
yGrjmAV5jlw7j5RFebDQu8RG2rLa/up9x/xHOU5eppGo7lm3uDTz6w5XxBYgB7ruYJFwW/2PiD9q
XjDEturp55IeLGM36+Tlz8JY6v8AXGhta9/4Ih62UvuWHuP3DfOg/wAGFg/g0mNKnahdifSKKua+
h0likOlp+yFa2FgP0rtOReVitRTIiUuJSjw6JpN4thVyhRdZ8EE/aYzn523NZeJYu7judhllHo0g
W5R3W8ajLwrgUJEDGKWN2kWvO5iB7qdKwB6MwwfqVrQKcObveZxZBtQNCp0vc//Z
--089e0118416874703004d86a5106--
```

Comment: As Jared suggested, reversing a simple mail is one of the easiest way to understand how to send it.
Your answer is really clear and one of the best I could find around ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the attachment into the body of the email message. Try something like this:

```
$random_hash = md5(time());

$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\"";

$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version 1.0";

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));

$message = 
"--PHP-alt-$random_hash
Content-Type: text/plain

Dear Same,

We would like to thank you for your registration to be held on Saturday August 25, 2012 at the....

--PHP-alt-$random_hash
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=$filename
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$attachment
--PHP-alt-$random_hash--";

@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: luk3thomas, the OP won't get it until the correlation of the mail packet with the output of the `mail()` function clicks.